# QuickBasic: Better alternative to INKEY$

Tags: basic, quickbasic

I have code that looks like this:

```
            IF INKEY$ <> "" THEN CALL notitle
        PLAY "MST170o1e8o0b8o1e8"
        IF INKEY$ <> "" THEN CALL notitle
        PLAY "e8e4f#8g4f#8"
        IF INKEY$ <> "" THEN CALL notitle
        PLAY "g4e8d2o0b8o1d2 "
        IF INKEY$ <> "" THEN CALL notitle
        PLAY "o1e8o0b8o1e8e8e4f#8g4f#8g4a8b2g8b2MLg16a16"
        IF INKEY$ <> "" THEN CALL notitle
        PLAY "MSb4b8b8a8g8a4a8a4f#8g4g8MLg8f#8"
        IF INKEY$ <> "" THEN CALL notitle
        PLAY "MSe8f#4f#8f#8g8a8b4.a4.g4.f#4.o0b8o1e8e8e4d8e2."
```

This seems pretty tedious. Is there a way to rewrite this more concisely? I believe the code is trying to provide the user with a way to skip through the music.

Comment: VB.NET, VB6, and QuickBasic are all different languages, and each has a separate tag for a reason. If your question is about QuickBasic, don't apply the other tags, because they're not anywhere near the same thing. Use tags that are appropriate to your question instead of just grabbing any that sound like what you're asking about; they're separate tags for a reason. Thanks.

Comment: I understand they are different languages...but generally folks who are experienced in VB6/VB.NET can answer a large proportion of questions in QuickBasic.

Comment: QuickBasic was a decade before VB.NET, and one has absolutely nothing to do with the other. VB6 was for creating Windows applications, while QB created DOS applications, so again there is zero similarity between them. Using all three tags is like asking an anatomy question and tagging it "animal", "vegetable" and "mineral" - IOW, nonsense. Please don't do so.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, programming QBasic in 2012 eh? What kind of project would that be?

Anyway, I would put the music strings into an array and loop through that array while checking INKEY$. I don't have QB installed so I'm not sure if this will work, but something like this:

```
DIM mymusic$(6)
FOR i = 1 TO 6
    READ S$
    mymusic$(i) = S$
NEXT i

' loop while user doesn't press any key
i = 0
WHILE INKEY$ = ""
  ' i will be 0..5 so play i+1 to get 1..6
  PLAY mymusic$(i+1)

  ' use MOD to loop i through 0..5
  i = (i + 1) MOD 6
WEND

' user pressed a key
CALL notitle

' music strings in data segment
DATA "MST170o1e8o0b8o1e8"
DATA "e8e4f#8g4f#8"
DATA "g4e8d2o0b8o1d2"
DATA "o1e8o0b8o1e8e8e4f#8g4f#8g4a8b2g8b2MLg16a16"
DATA "MSb4b8b8a8g8a4a8a4f#8g4g8MLg8f#8"
DATA "MSe8f#4f#8f#8g8a8b4.a4.g4.f#4.o0b8o1e8e8e4d8e2."
```

Btw you could break up the strings into shorter bits so it will check user input more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

This snip plays music from data in a loop in Qbasic:

```
' loop until keypress
i = 1
WHILE INKEY$ = ""
    RESTORE
    FOR j = 1 TO i
        READ p$
    NEXT
    PLAY p$
    i = i + 1
    IF i > 6 THEN i = 1
WEND

' user pressed a key
CALL notitle
' music strings in data segment
DATA "MST170o1e8o0b8o1e8"
DATA "e8e4f#8g4f#8"
DATA "g4e8d2o0b8o1d2"
DATA "o1e8o0b8o1e8e8e4f#8g4f#8g4a8b2g8b2MLg16a16"
DATA "MSb4b8b8a8g8a4a8a4f#8g4g8MLg8f#8"
DATA "MSe8f#4f#8f#8g8a8b4.a4.g4.f#4.o0b8o1e8e8e4d8e2."
```